# Show the set of nonnegative polynomials with fixed degree and weight one is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, linear-programming

Let ${\mathbb R}_n[X]$ denote the space of all polynomials of degree $\leq n$ with real coefficients. Since $(1,X,X^2,\ldots,X^n)$ is basis of it, we can view it as equipped with the usual Euclidean metric. Denote by $B$ the set of all $f\in{\mathbb R}_n[X]$ satisfying the two constraints $f\geq 0$ and $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx=1$.

**My question.** Show that $B$ is bounded (or find a counterexample).

**What I tried :** Since $f$ has degree at most $n$, we can apply a Lagrange polynomials decomposition :  there are polynomials $L_0,L_1,\ldots,L_n$ such that any $f\in {\mathbb R}_n[x]$ satisfies $f(x)=\sum_{j=0}^n f(\frac{j}{n})L_j(x)$.

So $B$ is bounded iff $B'=\lbrace (f(0),f(\frac{1}{n}),\ldots,f(1)) \ | \ f\in B\rbrace $ is.

It would suffice to show that there are positive constants $c_0,c_1,\ldots,c_n$ and $C$ such that $\sum_{j=0}^{n} c_jf(\frac{j}{n})=C$ (because then, $f(\frac{j}{n})\in[0,\frac{C}{c_j}]$ so $B'$ is bounded).

I have checked that this is indeed so for $n\geq 10$ ; for $n=6$ for example, one has

$$
41f(0)+216f(\frac{1}{6})+27f(\frac{2}{6})+272f(\frac{3}{6})+27f(\frac{4}{6})
+216f(\frac{5}{6})+41f(\frac{6}{6})=840
$$

The coefficient multiplying $f(0)$ seems to be the numerator of the $n$-th [Cotesian number](https://oeis.org/A002177) ; that's all I could find so far.

Comment: Isn't $\frac{x^2}{2}$ a counterexample for $n=2$? And in generally $\frac{x^{2k}}{2k}$ for even $n$?

Comment: Note that polynomials with odd degree cannot be $\ge 0$. Thus $B$ only contains polynomials with even degree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The set is bounded. Indeed, by definition the restriction of the set on $[0,1]$ has bounded $L_1$-norm: $\int_0^1 |f|\le 1$ because $f(x)\ge 0$. Since all norms on a finite dim Euclidean space are equivalent, the Euclidean norm of the space of restrictions is bounded, hence the coefficients of the polynomials are uniformly bounded.

Comment: Why does $\int f \leq 1$ imply that $\int f^{2} \leq 1$?

Comment: It should have been $L_1$-norm. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

On $\mathbb R_n[X]$ define a norm by $\|f\|=\int_0^{1}|f(x)|dx$. This makes the space a finite dimensional normed linear space. Consider the map $T$ on this space with values in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ (with its usual norm) which takes $ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n+1} a_kX^{k}$ to $(a_0,a_1,..,a_n)$. Any linear map on  finite dimensional normed linear space is continuous. Hence there exist a constant $C$ such that $\sqrt {\sum |a_k|^{2}} \leq C \int|f(x)|dx$. This proves your boundedness assertion.